# Rotate element and place in corner of parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position an element in the bottom right corner of it's parent. At the moment, you can see it's in the center, but touching the bottom:

http://jsfiddle.net/03r7gabp/

[image]

Ideally, I'd like it to be touching the bottom, flushed all the way to the right (what `right: 0;` typically does).

**This is the desired effect:**

[image]

Is this possible? I'm already using:

```
 transform-origin: bottom left;
```

Comment: .info { right: -49%; } ?

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's dependent on the window of `.info`. I have similar instances where it's not directly in the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of solutions to achieve that, however I found this one **more flexible**.

Due to the fact that you can combine multiple transform notations, you'll end up with:

```css
.info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; right: 0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(100%);
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
```

The key point is that a percentage value on `translate()` notation is relative to the size of bounding box. I.e. the size of border-box of the absolutely positioned element in this case.

Here is a demo:

```css
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;   
    position: relative;
}

.info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; right: 0;
    background-color: gold;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(100%);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(100%);
         -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(100%);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(100%);
            transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(100%);
    
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
         -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
            transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="info">
        hello this is a sentence
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so here's how I've done it!

**http://jsfiddle.net/03r7gabp/2/**

## CSS

```
.info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: lime;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 200px; /* height of container */
}
```

The only bodge that I'm not happy with is the `width` having to be a fixed value (equal to the height of the container).

## Breakdown

### Step 1

[image: Step 1]

Not much to see here, move along!

### Step 2

[image: Step 2]

Note that we've specified the origin of rotation to be the bottom left. Imagine you stick a pin in that corner of the `<div>` and you then spin it about this point.

### Step 3

[image: Step 3]

In the previous image our `<div>` was sat on the *outside* of the container. We can now adjust its margin to make it appear on the other side. Remember that the percentage specified is a measure of the width of the parent element

### Step 4

[image: Step 4]

Now we "bump" the item to the bottom of the container.

### Step 5

[image: Step 5]

Finally we have to give our `div` a width equal to the height of the parent container

---

An alternative solution would be to set the container to have `overflow: hidden;` and then put the width of the child element to arbitrarily large. Obviously if the length of sentence exceeded the height of the container, the words would be clipped (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/03r7gabp/6/)

Comment: +1 Here is another alternative: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/03r7gabp/7/ without specifying the `width`.

Comment: @HashemQolami nice solution! You should add that as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to change `transform-origin: bottom left;` to right and also change from`bottom: 0` to `top: 35px`

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="info">
    hello this is a sentence
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's better, but is there a way so `hello` is touching the corner? This might only be doable with JS if not.

Comment: check update code. Didn't realise you want to corner.

Comment: Thanks, how was 35px decided? Is it to do with the width of `.info`?

Comment: Is kinda hard for me to explain but you can read [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)